# how to update database column on session expire in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, user-inactivity

I want to update a database column on session expire after 15min of inactivity in laravel. Is there a way to trigger an update in the DB upon session expiration?

I have tried multiple solutions but it is not work for me. Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: You can't trigger an event on session expire, because there is canonically nothing to trigger that event. Either update the row the next time the user comes back, or run a cron that periodically checks for "expired" records.